# ORMLite select some columns using predicates

Tags: android, select, where-clause, ormlite

I have ORMLite database with some fields. I want to select titles from the table where id == id which I get from webservice. I do like that:

```
 try {
    Dao<ProcessStatus,Integer> dao = db.getStatusDao(); 
    Log.i("status",dao.queryForAll().toString());
    QueryBuilder<ProcessStatus,Integer> query = dao.queryBuilder();
    Where where = query.where();
    String a = null;
    for(Order r:LoginActivity.orders) {
        //LoginActivity.orders - array of my objects which I get from webservice
        Log.i("database",query.selectRaw("select title from process_status").
            where().rawComparison(ProcessStatus.STATUS_ID, "=",
                       r.getProcess_status().getProccessStatusId()).toString());
    }
    Log.i("sr",a);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried like this but I get only sets of my id, not titles. I tried like this:

```
Log.i("database", query.selectColumns(ProcessStatus.STATUS_TITLE).where().
    eq(ProcessStatus.STATUS_ID, r.getProcess_status().getProccessStatusId())
    .toString());
```

but I have the same result. How should I get data from database?

Comment: What is the result?  An exception?  Please edit your post with the exception if so.

Answer (score 14):

For selecting an specific field from the table, you could do something like this:

```
String result = "";
try {
    GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = yourDAO.queryRaw("select " +
        ProcessStatus.STATUS_TITLE +" from YourTable where "+ 
        ProcessStatus.STATUS_ID + " = " + 
        r.getProcess_status().getProccessStatusId());
    List<String[]> results = rawResults.getResults();
    // This will select the first result (the first and maybe only row returned)
    String[] resultArray = results.get(0);
    //This will select the first field in the result which should be the ID
    result = resultArray[0];
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to properly answer this question without seeing all of the classes of the `processStatusId` field and others.  However I think you are doing too much raw method and may not be properly escaping your values and the like.

I would recommend that you use the `IN` SQL statement instead of what you are doing in the loop.  Something like:

```
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Order r : LoginActivity.orders) {
    ids.add(r.getProcess_status().getProccessStatusId());
}
QueryBuilder<ProcessStatus, Integer> qb = dao.queryBuilder();
Where where = qb.where();
where.in(ProcessStatus.STATUS_ID, ids);
qb.selectColumns(ProcessStatus.STATUS_TITLE);
```

Now that you have built your query, either you can retrieve your `ProcessStatus` objects or you can get the titles themselves using `dao.queryForRaw(...)`:

```
List<ProcessStatus> results = qb.query();
// or use the prepareStatementString method to get raw results
GenericRawResults<String[]> results = dao.queryRaw(qb.prepareStatementString());
// each raw result would have a String[] with 1 element for the title
```