# Select specific columns from DB using ORMLite in Android (Full example needed)

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a model class:

```
    class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    String occupation;
    }
```

In ORMLite **queryForAll()** returns all the records which works like the following query:

**Select * From Person**

But I want only the 'name' column which will work like :

**Select 'name' From Person**.

I saw the following questions:
[ORMLite select some columns using predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866304/ormlite-select-some-columns-using-predicates)

[ORMLite Select Distinct Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190786/ormlite-select-distinct-fields)

But I need a full example for android.
Thanks!

Comment: ok. And what you will do?

Comment: Thanks. Pankaj Kumar.
I want to know is there any way to select specific column using Dao Method in ORMLite. 
If not then can u plz give me full example code which will select only name from person table.